# How to structure table for Distributed Change Control of a Row

Tags: sql, row

If I have a table named Person(ID, Name, Version), I want to make it so that users entering updates to existing person creates a newly versioned row.  Such that a person may take and make changes.  Exactly the same way Hg et al does versioning.  The idea is that if a person A enters x, person B can edit it and have a local copy of x.1, With all the beauty of merging back into x.

Would it be best to structure it like:
`Person(ID,Name,Version)`, and use some kind of Dewey system for revisions
or
`Person(ID,Name,Version, Creator)`, and use a Version local to the user
or some kind of
`Person(ID,Name,Person_Id, Creator)`,

Or are there better idea's for row centric versioning?

The end result in the UI would look like:

> You have x in your list
>
> person A has updated x [ignore],[update with A's changes]
>
> person B has updated x [ignore],[update with B's changes]

Comment: I recommend you look into inserting a row for every edit. This is better approach to avoid locks and will work faster. have two tables - one header and one "updates" where you will only insert and show latest version

Answer (score 0):

You could at a start and end date to the row:

```
PersonID  StartDt     EndDt        UpdatedBy   Other columns
1         2012-01-01  2012-02-01   Fred
1         2012-02-01  2012-03-01   Alice
1         2012-03-01               Thomas
```

Each edit is logged with the person that made the change.  You can also see during which period the row was active.  To search for the current row, you can use the condition that `EndDt is null`.